# Haskell: List Boundary

Tags: list, haskell, limit, list-comprehension, predicate

I have a list of doubles(myList), which I want to add to a new List (someList), but once the new list reaches a set size i.e. 25, I want to stop adding to it. I have tried implementing this function using sum but was unsuccessful. Example code below.
someList = [(a)| a <- myList, sum someList < 30]

Comment: Can you clarify the criterion for the list? Do you want `someList` to be the longest prefix of `myList` that has a sum `< 30`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
someList = makeList myList [] 0 where
    makeList (x:xs) ys total = let newTot = total + x
                               in if newTot >= 25
                                  then ys
                                  else makeList xs (ys ++ [x]) newTot
```

This takes elements from myList as long as their sum is less than 25.

The logic takes place in `makeList`. It takes the first element of the input list and adds it to the running total, to see if it's greater than 25. If it is, we shouldn't add it to the output list, and we finish recursing. Otherwise, we put `x` on the end of the output list (`ys`) and keep going with the rest of the input list.

Comment: @user2180045 - I've refactored my solution a little, it should run faster now :)

Comment: thanks again, give me a second to comprehend your previous solution :P

Answer (score 2):

The way @DanielFischer phrased the question is compatible with the Haskell way of thinking.

> Do you want someList to be the longest prefix of myList that has a sum < 30?

Here's how I'd approach it:  let's say our list is

```
>>> let list = [1..20]
```

we can find the "cumulative sums" using:

```
>>> let sums = tail . scanl (+) 0
>>> sums list
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,66,78,91,105,120,136,153,171,190,210]
```

Now zip that with the original list to get pairs of elements with the sum up to that point

```
>>> zip list (sums list)
[(1,1),(2,3),(3,6),(4,10),(5,15),(6,21),(7,28),(8,36),
 (9,45),(10,55),(11,66),(12,78),(13,91),(14,105),(15,120),
 (16,136),(17,153),(18,171),(19,190),(20,210)]
```

Then we can `takeWhile` this list to get the prefix we want:

```
>>> takeWhile (\x -> snd x < 30) (zip list (sums list))
[(1,1),(2,3),(3,6),(4,10),(5,15),(6,21),(7,28)]
```

finally we can get rid of the cumulative sums that we used to perform this calculation:

```
>>> map fst (takeWhile (\x -> snd x < 30) (zip list (sums list)))
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Note that because of laziness, this is as efficient as the recursive solutions -- only the sums up to the point where they fail the test need to be calculated.  This can be seen because the solution works on infinite lists (because if we needed to calculate all the sums, we would never finish).

I'd probably abstract this and take the limit as a parameter:

```
>>> :{
... let initial lim list =
...        map fst (takeWhile (\x -> snd x < lim) (zip list (sums list)))
... :}
```

This function has an obvious property it should satisfy, namely that the sum of a list should always be less than the limit (as long as the limit is greater than 0).  So we can use QuickCheck to make sure we did it right:

```
>>> import Test.QuickCheck
>>> quickCheck (\lim list -> lim > 0 ==> sum (initial lim list) < lim)
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you want is

```
ghci> appendWhileUnder 25 [1..5] [1..5]
[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3]
```

because that sums to 21 and adding the 4 would bring it to 25.

OK, one way to go about this is by just appending them with `++` then taking the initial segment that's under 25.

```
appendWhileUnder n xs ys = takeWhileUnder n (xs++ys)
```

I **don't** want to keep summing intermediate lists, so I'll keep track with how much I'm allowed (`n`).

```
takeWhileUnder n [] = []
takeWhileUnder n (x:xs) | x < n = x:takeWhileUnder (n-x) xs
                        | otherwise = []
```

Here I allow `x` through if it doesn't take me beyond what's left of my allowance.

Possibly undesired side effect: it'll chop out bits of the original list if it sums to over 25. Workaround: use

```
appendWhileUnder' n xs ys = xs ++ takeWhileUnder (n - sum xs)
```

which keeps the entire `xs` whether it brings you over `n` or not.

Comment: thanks Andrew, taking a break from code for a second, going to try out all answers given.